# Detect decimal number in Swift string

Tags: swift, parsing

I'd like to detect a number in a given String.

Examples are:

- 1
- 1.2
- 1,2
- 1.2kg
- 100mg

Please note that it is safe to assume the string always starts with the number, the number can be an integer or a decimal and the decimal separator can be a dot or a comma. Also you can assume a string does not contain multiple numbers.

As you can see from the examples a string can also contain a unit. I'd like to be able to get the range of the found number in order to get the remaining substring and to match that with a list of known units. However that range should be relative to a much bigger string. The string parsed here is only one token of a much larger string and I'd like to be able to get the range of the quantity in that larger string. Therefore the goal would be a function looking like this:

```
func scanQuantity(in string: String) -> (NSNumber, Range<String.Index>)?
```

Here is what I have. It kind of works however I am not sure how to a) get the range of the quantity inside of that larger string and
b) how to handle both decimal separator as scanDouble only works for one.

To make things clearer that is what I want to achieve:

```
I'd like to have 4kg bananas

Tokens: 
- I'd
- like
- to
- have
- 4kg
- bananas

I'd like to have 4kg bananas
                 ↑⇧⇧
↑: quantityRange
⇧: unitRange
```

```swift
func detect(in string: String) {
    let matches = string.matches(of: pattern)
    for match in matches {
        let token = match.output.0
        print("Scanning token: \(token)")
        if let quantity = scanQuantity(in: String(token), of: match.range) {
            print("Found quantity: \(quantity.value)")
        }
    }
}

private func scanQuantity(in token: String, of range: Range<String.Index>) -> Quantity? {
    let scanner = Scanner(string: token)
    #warning("this does not work for both comma and dot decimal separator")
    guard let quantity = scanner.scanDouble() else {
        return nil
    }
    
    if !scanner.isAtEnd {
        let unitSubstring = token[scanner.currentIndex...]
        print("Scanning for unit of quantity")
        print("Unit: \(unitSubstring)")
        #warning("how to get the range of the quantity in the whole string (relative to the range parameter)")
        return Quantity(value: NSNumber(value: quantity), range: range, unit: .piece)
    } else {
        return Quantity(value: NSNumber(value: quantity), range: range, unit: .piece)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new `Regex` functionality in swift

The pattern used is

```
let regex = /((\d+(\.|,?)\d*)([a-z]*))/
```

and then to evaluate the regex

```
someString.firstMatch(of: regex)
```

Example

```
let inputs = ["1", "1.2", "1,2", "1.2kg", "100mg", "I'd like to have 4kg bananas"]

for input in inputs {
    if let result = input.firstMatch(of: regex) {
        print((result.2, result.4))
    }
}
```

Output

> ("1", "")
> ("1.2", "")
> ("1,2", "")
> ("1.2", "kg")
> ("100", "mg")
> ("4", "kg")